# Sorting Arrays from Table

Tags: perl, sorting

Below is a code I have created to parse out from a table. The columns being parsed out are columns that are 0.5 or less in column 4. I want to sort the parsed out results that fit the parameter set.

Sample Data

```
bob smith 15 0.5
will smith 13 0.25
cool smith 12 1.0
```

Expected Output

```
will smith 0.25
bob smith 0.5
```

what I need to add to this script is a sort function based on the values in $data[3] preferably from lowest to highest. I am working with a much bigger set of data and names. I attempted to use sort { $a <=> $b } but I don't think I was using it correctly.

```
my $value;
open(FILE, $ARGV[0]) or die "Cannot open the file: $!";

   while(my $line = <FILE>)  {
   my @data = split(" ", $line);
   $value = "$data[3]";
   if ($value <= 0.5) { 
       print "$data[0]\t$data[1]\t$data[3]\n";
   }
}
close FILE;
exit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @selected;

while(my $line = <DATA>)  {
    my @data = split(" ", $line);
    if ($data[3] <= 0.5) {
        push @selected, \@data;
    }
}

@selected = sort {$a->[3] <=> $b->[3];} @selected;

for my $x (@selected) {
    print "$x->[0]\t$x->[1]\t$x->[3]\n";
}

__DATA__
bob smith 15 0.5
will smith 13 0.25
cool smith 12 1.0
```

Comment: I have a question about one of the functions you used. When you use push @selected, \@data  what specifically is it doing? I'm relatively new to perl and have not seen "\" before.

Comment: It pushes a "reference" to the array instead of the values. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html

Answer (score 3):

This is quite clear in a simple `map` / `grep`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print for sort {
  my ($aa, $bb) = map { (split)[3] } ($a, $b);
  $aa <=> $bb;
} grep { (split)[3] <= 0.5 } <DATA>;

__DATA__
bob smith 15 0.5
will smith 13 0.25
cool smith 12 1.0
```

or, as a variant of the Schwartzian Transform (which means this will probably run a little faster if that is a useful thing)

```
print $_->[-1] for
    sort { $a->[3] <=> $b->[3] }
    grep { $_->[3] <= 0.5 }
    map  { [ split, $_ ] } <DATA>;
```

#### output

```
will smith 13 0.25
bob smith 15 0.5
```